# Need to drive several 5 V LEDs from 3.3 V logic

Tags: led, logic-gates, led-driver, level-shifting

I have done similar level shifting several times using discrete components. This time, due to a need of driving some number of 5 V LEDs from a 3.3 V microcontroller, I prefer to use some level shifter IC for having smaller board space and overall cost.

I have plenty of I/O pins, so I will use a one-to-one pin connection, therefore, no SPI or I2C variants are required.

Let's say I need to drive four 5 V LEDs (embedded inside some buttons).
I've done some research and came across NAND gates as well as INVERTER gates for level shifting.

For a NAND example, the 74HC08 (4 NAND gates) looks promising and maybe even the 74HC132 which includes a Schmitt trigger.
For an INVERTER example, it is the SN74LVC2G07, but it has two channels. Four would be better for the sake of cost.

The 74HC08 has a max. output current of -+25 mA.
The SN74LVC2G07 has a max. output current of -+50 mA.

My questions may be looking opinion based, but I still need to verify my findings somehow, so I would like to ask you if those ICs would be wise to choose for such a simple LED driving purpose?

I assume there will be a current limiter for the LED. A basic schematic would be like this:

[image: schematic]

Image source: [Build Electronic Circuits - Open Collector Output – What Is It and How Do I Use It?](https://www.build-electronic-circuits.com/open-collector-outputs/)

Comment: 74ACTXX parts work nicely. The *TTL* compatible inputs interface well with 3.3 V logic. I like to use the 74ACT244.

Comment: You can pretty much forget all parts with "74HC", as HC will not work with 3.3V input. HCT would.

Comment: SN74LVC2G07 also has an absolute maximum current through Vcc or GND of 50mA (which you should get nowhere near) so *if you can have both on at once*, 10 or 15mA per output might be a reasonable limit.

Comment: **5V LED?** A strange animal - most LEDs require much less voltage to illuminate. Perhaps your pushbutton-LED incorporates a series resistor? If not, you might be able to drive a bare LED with 3.3V drive.

Comment: @glen_geek, yes, it is what I expect as well, there must be a current limiter in the button housing, I didn't get the datasheet yet but I am hoping later this week.

Comment: @Justme - I was under impression that HC versions have 3.3V input capability and HCTs are for only 5V. Thank you for clarifying this.

Comment: @Sener Nexperia has individual 6-pin devices that provide a single constant current driver for one LED, for example. But you write *some number* so these may not be what you want. There are also whole LED driver packages that handle 8 or more LED drivers with status info on each, etc. But these are usually serial devices and you've said you don't want that. I am generally opposed to the idea of using a resistor as a current limit for LEDs (very poor regulation) but this is especially important to me when the LEDs will be juxtapositioned next to each other where a human can compare them by eye.

Comment: @periblepsis - I am aware of them, they are quite robust and flexible devices, I would love to use them in the near future. For this project, I need to keep the software simple (without SPI or I2C libraries) as much as possible. I understand you concerns about poor regulation with current limiting resistor but, I believe it will not bring real harm by it at this time.

Comment: @Sener Understood. And that's your call. Most LEDs I use are either isolated indicators or else part of a display with enough adjacency to be a problem. This is especially made manifest with RGB LEDs where I want uniform white balance. There, I use custom voltage supplies for each color, coupled to settable "100%" currents for each color, and then use PWM within that to get the colors I want. A lot of work goes into the use of a spectrophotometer here, as well, so that I know the result is well-calibrated using CIE and some software I've written. It just works right. But there's work.

Comment: Why do you need to use an IC at all? Why not just use a logic-level N-Channel MOSFET configured as 'open-drain'?

Comment: I usualy like to use NPN BJT and P-Ch Mosfet combination. But, this time, I have restricted space and SOIC IC just fits with a few resistors. SOT23 components, four of them are always occupying more space than a single IC.

Answer (score 8):

Why use logic gates when there are ICs designed to do what you want?

Take a look at the ULN2003, it’s an array of 7 Darlington low-side drivers that should work with 3.3 V logic input. Output max current is 500 mA per output, max total current 2.5 A. Output voltage max 50 V.

Connect inputs to your I/O pins, LEDs and current limiting resistors to the outputs, easy peasy. Under $0.50 US each from major suppliers.

There are also similar driver ICs available with from 1 to 32 outputs.

Comment: Funny enough, this was my first option when I started to search IC level shifters. I have mainly used this with inductive loads so far. But, I wanted to decide what to use after a bit of search untill I am convinced at a certain method. Thank you for the pointer, noted.

Answer (score 7):

The `HCT` types of the [High Speed CMOS Logic Hex Buffer/Line Driver, Three-State Non-Inverting and Inverting](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd74hct365.pdf) could allow six 5V LEDs to driven by a 3.3 V microcontroller.

The VCC of the Hex Buffer would be set to 5 V. With the `HCT` types the TI datasheet linked above shows the V<sub>IH</sub> and V<sub>IL</sub> voltages should be compatible with 3.3 V microcontroller outputs:
[image]
[image]

As for the maximum LED current, in terms of the absolute maximum:

- For each output the absolute maximum is ±25 mA
- The absolute maximum over all six outputs is ±50 mA

As @CL pointed out in the other [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/698379/101063) you should keep away from operating at the absolute maximum ratings.

The datasheet doesn't contain curves which show the output voltage .vs. output current. However, for the `HCT` types the output voltages are shown for a TTL load of ±4 mA:
[image]
[image]

So, a reasonable current limit for one LED would be sinking 4 mA. I.e. a low turns on the LED.

Comment: +1. Using 20mA for a LED is very 1980's. These days modern indicator LEDs make you blind at this current. 1-2mA is great. HCT will work absolutely fine. 74HCT245 is the cheapest per channel (8 channels per chip).

Comment: I think I will give these HCT devices a try. Many users have already mentioned them confidently, and these devices can even come in small package sizes while being reasonably cheap per channel. I start with 74HCT125D.

Answer (score 3):

These current limits (±25 mA, ±50 mA) are absolute maximum ratings, i.e., exceeding them even by the smallest amount can damage the device. You should stay away from them. If you want to know how much current you can sink while still having enough of a voltage drop for the load, look at the test conditions for the guaranteed V<sub>OL</sub>; it's about 4 mA for HC with a 3.3 V supply, or 24 mA for LVC.

A device with a push/pull output like the 74HC08 cannot be used with a 3.3 V supply. When the output drives low, there is a voltage drop of about 5 V over the LED and the resistor; but when the output drives high, it is 3.3 V, so the remaining 1.7 V must still be dropped over the LED and the resistor. You have to check the characteristics of the LED to find out how much current flows, but some current will still flow.

The SN74LVC2G07 with a 3.3 V supply can be used to drive a LED; its open-drain output is disabled when the input signal is high, and the output is overvoltage tolerant.

There are devices that accept 3.3 V input signals with a 5 V supply. You can use any buffer with TTL-compatible inputs, e.g., ACT devices like the SN74ACT14/SN74ACT244 (HCT devices probably do not have enough drive strength for you). Alternatively, there are level shifters that have two supplies for input and output, like the TXU0104 or (SN)74LVC8T245.